# How do you get the id value of record inserted from a stored procedure using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 5 and am having trouble getting back the userId of a record that I inserted into the table. I've tried different ways of doing this but I've had no luck. All I get back is a -1 which I know is for rows affected. I can't seem to retrieve the UserID which is declared as an `OUTPUT` parameter for the stored procedure.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[User.Save]
    (@Return_Code  INT OUTPUT,
     @Error_Description_Code NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT,
     @idCallerSite INT = 0, --default if not specified
     @idCaller     INT = 0,
     @idUser       INT OUTPUT, 
     @firstName     NVARCHAR(50),
     @middleName    NVARCHAR(50),
     @lastName      NVARCHAR(50),
     @preferredName NVARCHAR(50),
     @username      NVARCHAR(512),
     @password      NVARCHAR(512),
     @isActive      BIT,
     @isSalesperson BIT,
     @userPreferences NVARCHAR(512),
     @phoneNumber     NVARCHAR(25),
     @phoneFax        NVARCHAR(25),
     @email           NVARCHAR(255),
     @photo           NVARCHAR(255),
     @lastEditedBy    INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @idPermission INT  -- define the permission required to perform this function
    SET @idPermission = 141
    
    /* 
    validate uniqueness
    */
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM Users
        WHERE SiteID = @idCallerSite
          AND (username = @username)
          AND (@idUser IS NULL OR @idUser <> UserID)) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Return_Code = 2
        SET @Error_Description_Code = 'UserSave_UserNotUnique'
        RETURN 1 
    END

    /*
    insert/update the user
    */

    IF (@idUser = 0 OR @idUser IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- insert the new user
        INSERT INTO Users (SiteID, firstName, middleName, lastName,
                           preferredName, username,
                           HashedPassword, isActive, IsSalesperson,
                           UserPreferences, PhoneNumber, FaxNumber,
                           EmailAddress, Photo, LastEditedBy)
        VALUES (@idCallerSite, @firstName, @middleName, @lastName,
                @preferredName, @username, 
                dbo.GetHashedString('SHA1', @password), @isActive, @isSalesperson,
                @userPreferences, @phoneNumber, @phoneFax,
                @email, @photo, @lastEditedBy)

        /*
        get the new user's id
        */

        SET @idUser = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        SELECT @idUser

        -- return successfully
        SET @Return_Code = 0 --(0 is 'success')
        SET @Error_Description_Code = ''
    END
```

Controller Call

```
var retCode = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Return_Code", Value = null, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Int), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };

var errorDesc = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Error_Description_Code", Value = null, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 50, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
var idCallerSite = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@idCallerSite", Value = 1, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Int), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var idCaller = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@idCaller", Value = 0, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Int), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var idUser = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@idUser", Value = user.UserID, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Int), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
var fName = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@firstName", Value = user.FirstName.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 50, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var mName = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@middleName", Value = user.MiddleName.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 50, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var lName = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@lastName", Value = user.LastName.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 50, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var pName = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@preferredName", Value = user.PreferredName.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 50, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var userName = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@username", Value = user.UserName.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 512, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var password = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@password", Value = user.HashedPassword.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 512, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var isActive = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@isActive", Value = user.IsActive, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Bit), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var isSalesperson = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@isSalesperson", Value = user.IsSalesperson, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Bit), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var userPref = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@userPreferences", Value = user.UserPreferences.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 512, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var phone = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@phoneNumber", Value = user.PhoneNumber.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 25, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var fax = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@phoneFax", Value = user.FaxNumber.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 25, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var email = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@email", Value = user.EmailAddress.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 255, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var photo = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@photo", Value = user.Photo.ToString(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Size = 255, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };
var lastEditedBy = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@lastEditedBy", Value = user.LastEditedBy, SqlDbType = (SqlDbType.Int), Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input };

var _user = await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC [dbo].[User.Save] @Return_Code, @Error_Description_Code, @idCallerSite, @idCaller, @idUser OUT, @firstName, @middleName, @lastName, @preferredName, @username, @password, @isActive, @isSalesperson, @userPreferences, @phoneNumber, @phoneFax, @email, @photo, @lastEditedBy", retCode, errorDesc, idCallerSite, idCaller, idUser, fName, mName, lName, pName, userName, password, isActive, isSalesperson, userPref, phone, fax, email, photo, lastEditedBy);

return Ok(_user);
```

I used `.FromSql` and got the following error.

```
var _user = _db.Users.FromSqlRaw("EXEC [dbo].[User.Save] @Return_Code, @Error_Description_Code, @idCallerSite, @idCaller, @idUser OUT, @firstName, @middleName, @lastName, @preferredName, @username, @password, @isActive, @isSalesperson, @userPreferences, @phoneNumber, @phoneFax, @email, @photo, @lastEditedBy", retCode, errorDesc, idCallerSite, idCaller, idUser, fName, mName, lName, pName, userName, password, isActive, isSalesperson, userPref, phone, fax, email, photo, lastEditedBy);
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'UserID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AsyncEnumerableReader.ReadInternal[T](Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AsyncEnumerableReader.ReadInternal[T](Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncEnumerable(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Object asyncEnumerable, Func`2 reader)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: fblo_329420117573382=y
Host: localhost:62374
Referer: http://localhost:62374/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Origin: http://localhost:62374
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

Comment: What is the result when you use `FromSql()` instead?

Comment: I get the following error System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'UserID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt of using `FromSql()` and the complete error message you get. It looks like you want to save a result in an object with the property/column `UserID`, however you have a `SELECT @idUser` statement which will return only an integer value (and you want to use the output parameters anyway).

Answer (score 0):

you can only use output parameter idUser to get record Id

```
_db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(....);

var id=0;

if (idUser.Value != DBNull.Value)
     {
        id = (int) idUser.Value;
     }
return Ok(id);
```

and fix stored procedure. Remove  SELECT @idUser, leave only

```
 SET @idUser = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

If sp contains SELECT Database.ExecuteSqlRaw always returns -1;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with doing a select statement with all the fields and then just extracted the UserID from the result set. Thank you @Progman for your assistance.  It was your suggestion that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework requires that at least the primary key is present, so you need to do

```sql
SET @idUser = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
SELECT UserID = @idUser;
```

However that only gets you one field, it won't get you any other columns. To get the other columns, you can just `OUTPUT` everything (no joins needed)

```sql
INSERT INTO Users (SiteID, firstName,
.........
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.SiteID, inserted.firstName
.........
        VALUES (@idCallerSite, @firstName
.........
```

> Note that the syntax you use to call the stored procedure is not ideal, as it relies on parameter position rather than name. Instead use `EXEC [dbo].[User.Save] @Return_Code = @Return_Code OUTPUT, @Error_Description_Code = @Error_Description_Code, @idCallerSite = @idCallerSite ...` you also need to specify `OUTPUT` on the output parameters as shown.